# ReactPHP how can I get requested URL into a variable?

Tags: php, reactphp

I need to parse some information from a bunch of sites and I have to have URLs from which I get the content. I use this library https://github.com/clue/reactphp-buzz . In this exsample i use only one URL. How can i get the URL which i send a request to?

```
  use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;


  $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
  $client = new Browser($loop);

  $client->get($url)
 ->then(function(\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) {
   $html = $response->getBody() . PHP_EOL;

  //here i need an url into a variable

  });

  $loop->run();
```

Comment: you passed it into `$client->get()`? Possibly your question isnt clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables through to anonymous functions with the `use`-keyword.

```
function(\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) use ($url) {
    // Now $url will be available inside the function
}
```

(notice the `use` before the opening brace)

You can read more about it under Example #3 in the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php